# What is the wrong in my code(all paths from source to target)?

Tags: recursion, graph, depth-first-search

Problem statement:
[Question link](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/)

> Given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of n nodes labeled from 0 to n - 1, find all possible paths from node 0 to node n - 1 and return them in any order.
>
> The graph is given as follows: graph[i] is a list of all nodes you can
> visit from node i (i.e., there is a directed edge from node i to node
> graph[i][j]).

Input:

```
[[1,2],[3],[3],[]]
```

Output:

```
[[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]
```

This is my code :

```
class Solution:
def allPathsSourceTargetUtil(self, n, graph, visited, ans):
    visited.append(n)
    
    if n == len(graph)-1:
        ans.append(visited)
        print(ans)
    else:
        for i in graph[n]:
            self.allPathsSourceTargetUtil(i, graph, visited, ans)
        
            visited.pop()
    
    
def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    ans  = []
    visited = []
    n = 0
    
    self.allPathsSourceTargetUtil(n, graph, visited, ans)
    
    return ans
```

And this is input:

```
[[1,2],[3],[3],[]]
```

And real Output:

```
[[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]
```

But I get this output from my code:

```
[[0, 1, 3]]
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3]]

[[0],[0]]
```

Please help me for find out problem in this code.

Comment: Hi Suman, what problem is your code supposed to be solving? How do you call the functions you define in the code you included?

Comment: Ooohhh! thank you bro, now i am updated my question.

Comment: `ans.append(visited)` should be `ans.append(visited[:])`. You need to copy the list when you find a result.